# How get a (fixed) value based on number range

Tags: php

I have a number, e.g. `$humidity`

I need to check value of this number and get a fixed value if number is in a predetermined range.

E.g.

```
if ($humidity<30) {
  return 'dry';
}
if ($humidity>=30 && $humidity <=40) {
 return 'wet'
}
if ($humidty>40 && $humidity<70) {
 return 'confortable'
}
```

And so on.

Is there another possibility to don't use 4/5 different `if` ?

Comment: What about using Switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think switch is great for this usage:

```
$result = null;

switch(true) {
    case $humidity < 30:
        $result = 'dry';
        break;

    case $humidity >= 30 && $humidity < 40:
        $result = 'wet';
        break;

    case $humidty > 40 && $humidity < 70:
        $result = 'comfortable';
        break;
}

return $result;
```

Comment: Too hot there days, I didn't get this idea :) Thank you :)

Comment: Note that the greater than checks are not needed. I.e., if you get to the second case, you've already ensured that `$humidity >= 30`.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you process the values in order, you don't need both the upper and lower values of each range. Then you can utilize short-circuiting and just put everything in a loop:

```
function nameOf($humidity)
{
    $list = [
        30 => 'dry',
        40 => 'wet',
        70 => 'comfortable',
    ];
    foreach ($list as $value => $name) {
        if ($humidity < $value) {
            return $name;
        }
    }
    return 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an range array for your temps and then array_walk that to find the right range.

```
$h=40;
$harr = [ 0 => 'dry', 1 => 'wet', 2 => 'confy'];
$range = array_flip(range(0, 100, 30));
array_walk($range, 'findHumidity', $range);
var_dump($harr[$result]);

function findHumidity($value, $key, $r){
    global $h; //if you using a class and properties you can ignore these two lines
    global $result;
    $normalRange = array_flip($r);
    if($h> $key && $normalRange[$value+1]!=null && $h<= $normalRange[$value+1]){
        $result = $value;
    }
}
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/fWLDu (a simplified version: https://3v4l.org/ROjWk)
or you can define the range array manually like here: https://3v4l.org/B0oTU